# comparison of characters in C & python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a C code in python:

```
int main()
{
  char ch=291;
  printf("%d %c",ch,ch);
  return 0;
}
```

In python:

```
ch=291
print "%d %c" % (ch,ch)
```

But it's giving an error...

In C ,character value after 255 again returns to 0, Is that type of concept is not applicable for python?

Comment: In python print syntax is different 

check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041791/print-variable-and-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's actually giving:

```
OverflowError: unsigned byte integer is greater than maximum
```

and it's because the `%c` format expects a single byte, which is `0x11111111` (255) maximum. And 291 is `0b100100011` which is 9 bits.

In `c` I'm not sure why it shows `0`, but it's definitely a way to tell you there's an error, overflowing the byte in the format.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ch=291   
>>> print "%d %s" % (ch,ch)
    291 291
```

Here ch is variable where assign as 291 value. Use %s for string.