# How can I change my string that is called x?

Tags: python

```
x = "a"
count = 3

#I need the x to be like the string above when i print...

#print(x) #output---------> a:3
```

How I do this guys? thank you very much! and one more thing- i need x to change his value to the value of the print result...

Comment: `print(f"{x}:{count}")`

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. Python has at least 3 ways to do string formatting (the `format()` function, the `%` operator, and f-strings). You can also convert `count` to a string and then use concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, I need to change the value of x, not only to print him like this. by the way...

Comment: `x += f":{count}" ; print(x)`?

Comment: `f"{var}"` is only supported in Python 3.6>=, so be aware of which version you're running

Comment: @Wondercricket Given that only Python 3.8 and newer are officially supported, and Python 3.5 stopped receiving security updates over 2 months ago, 3.6 isn't a bad minimum version to assume

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print variable and a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041791/print-variable-and-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
print( f"{x}:{count}" )
```

the `f` in front of the string is shortcut for `str.Format()`. So essentially you can execute any code inside the `{}`.

Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "a"
count = 3
print(x+':'+str(count)) #output a:3
```