# How to print a range of year with explanation?

Tags: python

So i have this task to determine which is the leap year(tahun kabisat in indonesia).
for example the user input 1945-1950
i need to make the output looks like this
1945 is not a leap year
1946 is not/ a leap year
1947...
1948...

i have done it this far but i dont know how to print it, im sorry im a beginner hehe thanks

```
def kabisat(Tahun):
   if Tahun % 400 == 0:
      Leap = True
   else:
      if Tahun % 100 == 0:
          Leap = False
      elif Tahun % 4 == 0:
          Leap = True
      else:
          Leap = False
   return Leap
Tahun = (input("Masukkan rentang tahun: ")).split('-')
print(Tahun)
Awal = int(Tahun[0])
Akhir = int(Tahun[1])
for Tahun in range(Awal,Akhir+1):
    if kabisat(Tahun)==Tahun:
      print({Tahun}, "adalah tahun kabisat")
```

Comment: Change `if kabisat(Tahun)==Tahun` to `if kabisat(Tahun)==True` or simply `if kabisat(Tahun)` because the `kabisat` function returns a boolean value.

Comment: wow thankyou somuchhh

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print variable and a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041791/print-variable-and-a-string-in-python)